# startActivityForResult, but not on my app's activity stack?

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

My app reaches out to the camera activity to take a picture.

On most devices, this works just fine.  On lower end devices, like the moto droid, my app pushes the heap to almost the max.  As a result, calling the camera activity kills my app in the background on these lower devices.

Is there a way to call the camera activity without it adding to MY app's heap size?  Can it be it's own heap?

Comment: Do you mean that your app crashes, or that the calling activity is destroyed and then restarted after the camera does its work?

Comment: I actually don't get a force close, but the activity that calls the camera disappears, and it returns back to my MainMenu activity.  Another odd thing to note is that after this happens, if I press the back button with the MainMenu showing, it keeps re-loading my MainMenu activity until about the 4th time that I hit back, when it finally exits my app.

Comment: Can you post the code? Also, can you log which activity life cycle calls are being invoked as all this happens?